# How to make an object nested property be part of the object itself?

Tags: javascript

Since the question can feel a bit weird, let me explain by an example:

Given an object like this:

```
{
  id
  attributes: {
    name
  }
}
```

If I want to access the name, it must be done by `thatObject.attributes.name`.

What I want to achieve, is that by writting `thatObject.name` it automatically searches for it in the attributes property.

How's that possible to achieve?

Comment: It isn't possible. `thatObject` and `attributes` are completely different objects. `attributes` has no knowledge of `thatObject`. If `attributes` was the prototype for `thatObject` then that would be different.

Comment: You can do it using proxy's, but is is not a good idea

Comment: What if `name` were to exist in multiple sub-objects? This just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Your sample is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
var obj = {  
  attributes: {
    name:"somevalue",
    otherthing:"flazm"
  },
  get name() { 
    return this.attributes.name;
  },
};
```

Comment: Already thought about that. The thing is I wanna do that for all properties under attributes property to happen in an automated way, so not to explicitly declare a getter per sub-property

Comment: Hmm. thought about using jquery extends?  `$.extend(targetObject, attributes)`.  You'd end up with targetObject having all properties of `attributes` - but it would overwrite any same-named properties on the target.

Answer (score 0):

I think by using JavaScript getter, you can achieve what you wanted. See example:

```
var obj = {
  get name () {
    return this.attributes.name;
  },
  attributes : {name : 'the name'}
}

console.log(obj.name); -> the name
```

by modifying the body of getter, you can return whatever you want